# Correct way to hard code command line arguments

Tags: c

Following code basiaclly lets access to GPIO port with LED.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern char *optarg;
    char *cptr;
    int gpio_value = 0;
    int nchannel = 0;

    int c;
    int i;

    opterr = 0;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "g:io:ck")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'g':
                gl_gpio_base = (int)strtoul(optarg, &cptr, 0);
                if (cptr == optarg)
                    usage(argv[0]);
                break;
            case 'i':
                gpio_opt = IN;
                break;
            case 'o':
                gpio_opt = OUT;
                gpio_value = (int)strtoul(optarg, &cptr, 0);
                if (cptr == optarg)
                    usage(argv[0]);
                break;
            case 'c':
                gpio_opt = CYLON;
                break;
            case 'k':
                gpio_opt = KIT;
                break;
            case '?':
                usage(argv[0]);
            default:
                usage(argv[0]);

        }
    }

    if (gl_gpio_base == 0) {
        usage(argv[0]);
    }

    nchannel = open_gpio_channel(gl_gpio_base);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler); /* catch kill signal */
    signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler); /* catch hang up signal */
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler); /* catch quit signal */
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler); /* catch a CTRL-c signal */
    switch (gpio_opt) {
        case IN:
            set_gpio_direction(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, "in");
            gpio_value=get_gpio_value(gl_gpio_base, nchannel);
            fprintf(stdout,"0x%08X\n", gpio_value);
            break;
        case OUT:
            set_gpio_direction(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, "out");
            set_gpio_value(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, gpio_value);
            break;
        case CYLON:
#define CYLON_DELAY_USECS (10000)
            set_gpio_direction(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, "out");
            for (;;) {
                for(i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(cylon); i++) {
                    gpio_value=(int)cylon[i];
                    set_gpio_value(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, gpio_value);
                }
                usleep(CYLON_DELAY_USECS);
            }
        case KIT:
#define KIT_DELAY_USECS (10000)
            set_gpio_direction(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, "out");
            for (;;) {
                for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE(kit); i++) {
                    gpio_value=(int)kit[i];
                    set_gpio_value(gl_gpio_base, nchannel, gpio_value);
                }
                usleep(KIT_DELAY_USECS);
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    close_gpio_channel(gl_gpio_base);
    return 0;
}
```

Genarlly I would give commands like this;

```
gpio-demo -g 255 -o 0
```

255 above tells me chip number, 000 tells me what data will go to GPIO port.

This would turn off all the LEDs.

However for some debugging purpose I have to modify  this code such that it behaves a litlle differently:

When running teh program, tt should simply switch off the LED i.e run the following command.

```
gpio-demo -g 255 -o 0
```

This is the only command that will work- hard coded. 
An ON LED will be now OFF.

What I tried is I inserted the command  as the first line in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {


argv = "gpio-demo -g 255 -o 0"  //irrespective of what user what user type, run this command. gpio-demo is the binary of this program 
.
.
.
.

    }
```

is this the correct way to hard code command line arguments ?

Comment: `char *argv2[] = {"gpio-demo", "-g", "255", "o", "0"}; argv = argv2;`

Comment: @someuser: +1, but you also need to fix `argc`, and it's a good idea to terminate `argv[]` with a `NULL`.

Comment: I would just initialize all variables with proper values and comment the whole `getopt()` loop

Comment: Why post over twice as much code necessary to show your issue?

Comment: The first parameter of argv2 should be argv[0] in case the filename is not gpio-demo.  Side note: a break is needed after usage otherwise ? will print the help twice.

Comment: @Jayesh yes. gpio-demo is the binary of this program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call you program like this `gpio-demo -g 255 -o 0`, than `argc` would be equal to `5` and `argv` will be a list of five pointers to sequences of characters where the first is `gpio-demo`, the second `-g`, the third `255`, ...

So if you really want to hardcode, you would have to write:

```
argc = 5;
argv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*argc);
argv[0] = "gpio-demo";
argv[1] = "-g";
argv[2] = "255";
argv[3] = "-o";
argv[4] = "0";
```

However, I would not recommend this! Rather use a bash script with the desired command line.

Comment: Thsi gives error while compiling: 'gpio-demo.c: In function 'int open_gpio_channel(int)':
gpio-demo.c:73: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
gpio-demo.c: In function 'int close_gpio_channel(int)':
gpio-demo.c:118: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
gpio-demo.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
gpio-demo.c:256: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**''

Comment: gpio-demo.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)': gpio-demo.c:256: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**

Comment: You are sure this is a C question and not a C++ question? Anyway I updated my answer to a safe version.

Comment: This worked pretty fine. I was compiling with C++ compiler so itw as giving those errors. But I have to write entire command gpio-demo -g 255 o 0. I was expecting that I would just give gpio-demo , and it would basically run gpio-demo -g 255 o 0

Comment: @user2799508: So what is not working as expected right now? Please describe the problem.

Comment: Actually the binary gpio-demo will be called by another program. And thsi binary would not run. This is because I checked on console that only typing the full command works: gpio-demo -g 255 -o 0 . But if I type gpio-demo , it does not work. instead the function usage() starts and tell me how to use the command. Shall I remove input param from main()

Comment: Did you assigned all 5 values?

Comment: yes, added all 5 vlaues: argc = 5;
argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*argc);
argv[0] = "gpio-demo";
argv[1] = "-g";
argv[2] = "255";
argv[3] = "-o";
argv[4] = "0";